# Catching errors in a Perl REST API

Tags: perl, rest, mojolicious

I am coding a REST API using Perl/Mojolicious
Sometimes when I want to throw an error, for example "Invalid token" I store the error on a variable called "Object->lastError" and then I render the JSON response with the error message/code.

However it gets tedious to do it that way after a while. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this I was considering just dying and catching the die error with`$SIG{__DIE__}`

Any suggestions? 
Also, I am not using any logger yet but I would like to log those errors

Comment: Take a look at hooks. Maybe you can hook around the dispatching and Try::Tiny in there to catch errors.

Answer (score 0):

On the question of logging, see: http://search.cpan.org/~garu/MojoX-Log-Log4perl-0.10/lib/MojoX/Log/Log4perl.pm Log4perl is pretty much best practice in the wider Perl world.

Without knowing a lot of deep detail about the application, I far prefer your 'tedious' method which will [hopefully] provide some information on the receiving side of the API, rather than a crash and burn with `$SIG{__DIE__}`.

Hope that helps, a bit, anyway!